# How to apply combinatorics on pairs in sql database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to perform some kind of combinatorics from a database.

my database table:

```
start  | end    | costs | date
____________________________________
berlin | Moscow |   100 | 2014-12-10
berlin | paris  |   200 | 2014-12-13
Moscow | berlin |   150 | 2014-12-20
Moscow | berlin |   100 | 2014-12-11
```

Possible pairs are all `start-end` combinations that have an equal combination of`end-start`.
In my table, this applies to `berlin-moscow` and `moscow-berlin`.

I want to compute "roundtrips" going from one city to another, and returning later to the same startcity.

The resulting table I want to achieve would be:

```
start  | end    | costs | away       | wayback
berlin | moscow |   250 | 2014-12-10 | 2014-12-20
berlin | moscow |   200 | 2014-12-10 | 2014-12-11
```

(this implies that when starting in berlin and going to moscow, the wayback will be moscow-berlin).

Is that possible with database queries?

First of all: how could I selfjoin a tables and get all distinct `start-end` pairs?

Comment: What exactly is your goal? 1) find out if there is a path from A to B 2) find the patth wich the lowest cost ? 3) find the number of paths ? 4) detect if there are loops in the graph (there will be ;-) UPDATE: yes: can be done with (recursive) queries. Avoiding lopps is the biggest problem.

Comment: I want to find the path from A-B-B with the lowest cost regarding the pair of away-wayback date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a comment, i would advise you to not use reserved words as `End` for user defined objects as tables or columns.

```
SELECT F.Start,
       F."end",
       F.costs + R.costs AS costs,
       F.date AS away,
       R.date AS wayback 
FROM   Table1 F
       JOIN Table1 R
           ON F."end" = R.Start
           AND R.date>F.date
           AND F.start = R."end"
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/11d4e/2)**

Comment: Great. That gets my going on my goal.

Comment: +1.  Any particular reason why you decided to put half of the condition in the JOIN clause, and the other half in the WHERE clause though?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Not really, except that it was done in two different edits...:) I will move them all in the JOIN.

Comment: Postgres does not use `[]` for escaping column names. Your query would cause an error. Use - `F."end"`.